# Python3.0 ファイル出力の改行が2行分になる

Tags: python3, テキストファイル

Pythonを使ってファイルにデータを出力しようとしています。

以下のコードを実行すると1行ではなく、2行分改行されます。

```
f = open(fileName, "a")
f.write(data + os.linesep)
f.close()
```

一行分の改行を行うにはどうすればいいでしょうか。

Comment: 2行分改行されるのは変数 `data` の末尾に改行コード(`os.linesep`)が含まれているからだと考えられるのですが、常にそうなのであれば `f.write(data)` だけで良さそうな気もします。末尾に改行コードがない場合もあるのでしたら、`f.write(data.strip(os.linesep) + os.linesep)` とするなどの対応もあり得るかと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。f.write(data)にすると0行f.write(data.strip(os.linesep) + os.linesep)にすると2行になりました。

Comment: すみません、すっかり勘違いをしていました。payanecoさんの解答を参照して下さい。

Comment: いえいえ、回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 11, accepted):

pythonは`\n`を自動的に[OS固有の改行に変換する](https://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)ため、`os.linesep`をWindowsで使うと余分な改行が入る場合があります。

サンプルコード:

```
import os
with open('hoge.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('hello' + os.linesep)
    f.write('world!')

with open('hoge.txt', 'r') as f: #テキストモードで開く
    print(f.read())

with open('hoge.txt', 'br') as f: #バイナリモードで開く(改行コードなども表示できる)
    print(f.read())
```

出力結果:
hello

world!
b'hello\r\r\nworld!'

上記のように2行分改行されたように見えます。(Windowsのメモ帳で開くと1行分の改行に見えるところが厄介ですが…)
`os.linesep`は`\r\n`を出力しますが、自動変換で`\n`が`\r\n`になるのでバイナリモードで開くと`\r\r\n`になってしまうのが原因です。

テキストモード(openの第二引数が'b'でない場合)でデータを出力する時は、`os.linesep`ではなく`\n`を使用しましょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。動作確認しました。Windowsのメモ帳で開くと1行分の改行に見えるところが厄介というのはまさにその通りでした。